# Magento2 In Store/Configuration/General/Design I can only see Search Engine Robots section

Tags: magento2

so all I see is this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

(On this second image is actual Store/Configuration/General/Design section)

Any idea what files might be missing?

Answer (score 4):

I believe they moved it to the design tab in a newer version.

Comment: Exactly, for some funny reason server guys installed v2.0.0 :)

Comment: yup - i found this in Content > Design > Configuration

Answer (score 1):

For those that are still having problem with the logo. If you want to change your logo:

1. On the Admin sidebar, tap Content. Then under Design, choose Configuration.
2. Find the store view that you want to configure, and in the Action column, click Edit.
3. Expand  the Header section. Then, do the following: 
   a.  To upload a new logo, tap Upload. Then, choose the file from your computer.
   b.  Enter the Logo Image Width and Logo Image Height.
   c.  In the Logo Image Alt field, enter the text that you want to appear when someone hovers over the image.
4. When complete, tap Save Configuration.

Magento reference link:
  http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/design/logo-upload.html

Answer (score 1):

check **CONTENT** > **Configuration** page (not in Stores>Configuration)!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following file describes "HTML Head", "Search Engine Robots", "Header", etc. fields groups:
vendor/magento/module-theme/etc/adminhtml/system.xml
You see only one of them, so it is not a files issue.

Ensure you have proper ACL permissions set for your "admin" user.