# Magento 2.1.0 --) STORES - CONFIGURATION - GENERAL - Design --) shows "Search Engine Robots"

Tags: magento2, configuration, design

I installed Magento version 2.1.0. When I go into **STORES -> CONFIGURATION -> GENERAL -> Design ->** it shows "Search Engine Robots" just as here:

[Magento2 In Store/Configuration/General/Design I can only see Search Engine Robots section](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115944/magento2-in-store-configuration-general-design-i-can-only-see-search-engine-robo)

Is there something wrong with my installation/configuration? It seems not logical. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with your installation. I believe they moved it to the design tab in a newer version.

In my 2.1 version also it shows same. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1aJL9nhfbfFZ3JKeWszcVczSjQ/view?usp=drivesdk

It seems the theme configuration was moved.

It can be found in main administration menu:

Content -> Design -> Configuration
Click on scope you are interested in(probably the first one) and change 'Applied theme'.

Answer (score 2):

After Magento new version it has been moved to Content -> Design -> Configuration  and from here you can make changes to select theme.