# Where is "Search Engine Robots" configuration panel in Magento 2.2?

Tags: admin, system-config, magento2.2.0

I [see](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/search-engine-robots.html), that "Search Engine Robots" should be in "Stores / Configuration / General / Design" path. I [see](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130798/magento-2-1-0-stores-configuration-general-design-shows-search-en) that this panel was there in Magento 2.1. But I cannot see "Design" section at all in the fresh Magento 2.2.0 installation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go to Content -> Design -> Configuration in admin panel

Select your current from the grid and click edit from action column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Refer this in `Content > Design > Configuration` Select your current from the grid and click **edit** from action column.

You will find the setting for **Search Engine Robots**.